# The Install Android SDK is too old.Version 24.3.4

Tags: android

I have same problem but i am not found Android SDK 24.3.0/Any one please help to select exact option required.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHrfB.png)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to download the `API 24` from the sdk manager, the latest revision will be downloaded and installed.